# In Azure Service Bus Premium tier, how many operations per month can 1 MU handle?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

In Service Bus Basic and Standard, the cost is partially determined by number of operations. In Service Bus Premium tier, how many operations per month can 1 MU handle?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like there isn't really a clear cut answer. With Service Bus Premium, each 1 Messaging Unit (MU) is hosted behind the scenes by a dedicated Virtual Machine (VM). The VM used is likely the same VM size that Service Bus Basic and Standard are using, except with Premium you get a dedicated VM for each 1 MU you are paying for.

Since it's based on dedicated VMs, your "operations per month" will vary depending on which Azure Service Bus services you use and how your load is distributed amongst the different Service Bus features.

As is the fashion for any other service within Azure, the VMs used to host 1 MU is likely to be 2 VMs in order to provide proper fail-over for the 99.9% SLA guarantee that Service Bus Premium will get once it's out of Preview and reaches General Availability.

Here's a couple quotes I was able to find to gleam a little detail into this:

> A Service Bus Premium Messaging namespace with 4 “Messaging Units” is roughly equivalent to a set of 4 primary broker VMs, with further, matching standby failover capacity.

via https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-service-bus-premium-messaging/

> A Messaging Unit is a set of dedicated resources exclusively reserved for Premium namespaces.

via https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/service-bus/